# Spacebar key doesn't work on a TextField only for Flutter Web Production build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Whenever I try to press "*Space*" inside a **TextField** of a Flutter Web release(production) it doesn't do anything. However, the behavior does not replicate on a flutter web debug environment.
What I found so far:

- Flutter Web was supported only by Chrome broswer, but as of now - Chrome, Safari, Edge, Firefox are supported [(See Flutter Documentation)](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web)
- The problem does not reproduce on Chrome browser, even in release build.

**Update**: Works after upgrading to Flutter 2.10

Comment: What browser are you testing on?

Comment: I have tested it on Brave, Microsoft Edge, and Chrome. Only Chrome seems to work

Comment: Try building with html web renderer instead of canvas kit - use this command: `flutter build web --web-renderer html --release`

Comment: Update: Works after upgrading to Flutter 2.10

Comment: I'm using Flutter 2.10.3, still facing the issue.

Comment: @Josteve build using HTML renderer did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Spacebar won't work if you are using `Textfield` or `TextFormField` inside SingleChildScrollView or ListView on Flutter web.

As it will take its default behavior which is to scroll the screen.

To avoid this, set the `primary` property of your scrollable widget to `false`.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    primary: false,  //<------- this one, by default it is true
    child: TextFormField(...),
    )
```

Comment: even adding "primary: false" with flutter 3.0.5 I am having the same problem. any solution?

Comment: Please share your widget tree hierarchy @MaurizioMancini

Comment: thanks for your concern but i solved it

Comment: @MaurizioMancini I'm struggling with it on Flutter 3.7.11

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by modifying the MaterialApp in the following way

```
return MaterialApp(
   shortcuts: {
     LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.space): ActivateIntent(),
   },
   //...
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return MaterialApp(
   shortcuts: {
     LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.space): ActivateIntent(),
   },
   //...
 );
```

Doing this will break FocusTraversalGroup and FocusTraversalOrder making the tab key  tab through your browser's buttons instead.  Even with KeyboardListener('s) listening to tab and this recommended code, tab will still tab through the browser's buttons like next and favorites in addition to your listeners and focus nodes:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            // console.log('event key'+event.code);
            if (event.code == 'Tab') {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```