# Space bar key doesn't work on textfields ( Flutter Web )

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

In our application, SOMETIMES space input doesn't work in textFields (f.e. adding a new message in a chat), but after refreshing the page it works again. This situation is causing unstable environment for our users and thus a lot of complaints. Is there any official documentation, or solution by flutter for this "sometimes space button cannot be used" problem. What we notices that, when this problem occurs, fonts are different than it supposed to be, like it's not loaded. It is not browser specific because problem occurs at Chrome & Edge.

The real problem is that the bug is not easy to detect because it happens only few times so i don't know how to detect and solve it.
In particular i noted that it happens only in production ( i never spotted it during development) .

Flutter doctor:

[image: Flutter doctor]

This is an example widget that have the bug

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CustomAlertDialog(
    title: const Text(
      "Aggiungi un messaggio",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
    ),
    actions: [
      TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Text(
            "Annulla",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
          )),
      TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            
          },
          child: const Text("Invia"))
    ],
    content: Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
              width: 800,
              child: TextField(
                minLines: 8,
                maxLines: 8,
                autofocus: false,
                controller: _chatController,
                //keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                onChanged: (text) {
                  setState(() {
                    textValue = text;
                  });
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  hintText: "Scrivi qui il tuo messaggio",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            CheckboxListTile(
              value: _hiddenMessage,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _hiddenMessage = value!;
                });
              },
              title: const Text("Nascondi"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

}

CustomAlertDialog:

```
class _CustomAlertDialogState extends State<CustomAlertDialog> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      insetPadding: widget.insetPadding ??
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 24.0),
      title: widget.title ??
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const [
              Icon(
                Icons.cancel,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 30,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text('Errore'),
            ],
          ),
      elevation: widget.elevation ?? 24.0,
      actions: widget.actions ??
          [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("Ok"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
      content: widget.content ??
          const Text(
            "Errore di connessione al server",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I already tried a lot of solutions available on stackOverflow but nothing works

Comment: Hey, which solutions did you try?

Comment: I tried this solutions: - Add LogicalKeySet in materialApp .  - Change Flutter SDK version  - Removed AlertDialog and used a simple Dialog

Comment: Did you also try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953283/5812524 ? Looks like your TextField is inside a SingleChildScrollView, so this should be your case

Comment: Still having the bug..

Comment: @CesareIsHere Have you fixed the issue? I'm struggling with it

Comment: @MinhNguyen Hi, i resolved that by doing flutter clean -> pub get and than rebuilding apps. I think the problem was in a Flutter update were they updated the index.js file and my version was older.

Comment: @CesareIsHere I've tried your suggestion, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   shortcuts: {
     LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.space): ActivateIntent(),
   },
   title: 'title of your app',
   //....
 );
}
```

Comment: Hi, i already tried this and it doesnt work

Comment: It helped me. But after a while, I realized some shortcuts weren't working. So Instead of overriding all of it with this map, it is best to just add it to the existent shortcuts:

'''
Map.of(WidgetsApp.defaultShortcuts)
      ..addAll({
        LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.space): const ActivateIntent(),
      });
'''

Comment: And I just checked the default shortcuts and this one is already there now. I'm not sure if it is something new...