# Could not enter white space characters in TextField in Release Mode

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a Flutter Web app and usually not able to type the white space in `TextFields` after I press Tab to move the focus to next `TextField`. It only happens in Release Mode.

I've tried some suggestions from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004441/spacebar-key-doesnt-work-on-a-textfield-only-for-flutter-web-production-build)

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261
> darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 3.7.10 on channel stable at /Users/minhnguyen/Library/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision 4b12645012 (9 days ago), 2023-04-03 17:46:48 -0700
> • Engine revision ec975089ac
> • Dart version 2.19.6
> • DevTools version 2.20.1

Did anyone encounter this issue and have any suggestions?

Comment: _"It's only happy in Release Mode."_ Do you mean it works OK in release mode, or do you mean **it only happens** in release mode?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry about my typos, I meant "it only happens in Release Mode"