Space key doesnt work in Flutter Web TextField/TextFormField
Create a StatefulWidget with Widget Tree Scaffold -> SingleChildScrollView -> Column ->
Row -> children (Expanded -> TextField/TextFormField), (Expanded -> TextField/TextFormField)
Deployed on web server firebase hosting and tried, didn't work
Flutter version: Flutter 3.22.3 stable
Duplicate issue: #74191
Expected results:
Just like normal JavaScript web, allow to jump from one field or dropdown to the next
Actual results:
Try typing "abc def" and press Tab key to jump to next text field. Again attempt to type with Space Key. Not working.
IMPORTANT Tab key is required for any web application. Please resolve this issue.
Tried to add below code, and Tab key stops working, and many users are complaining
Column(children: [
          SizedBox(
            child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                        child: TextFormField(
                            focusNode: _nameFocus,
                            onFieldSubmitted: (text) =>                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_discreptionFocus),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: fieldName,
                              border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                              ),

                            ),
                            controller: controllerTest
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          focusNode: _nameFocus,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (text) => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_discreptionFocus),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: fieldName,
                              border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                              ),

                            ),
                            controller: controllerOther
                        )
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
          ),
          
        ])


Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71004441/13993137
